# What are recommended Re-index settings?

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexing

What are the recommended re-index settings? We run a store that has around 8,000 SKUs and is connected to a Warehouse Management System which processes our Amazon orders as well.

Currently we have everything set up for Update on Schedule, however I read over on the Sonassi blog: https://www.sonassi.com/help/magento-management/index-management
That it might be good to have the Product Stock and Product Prices set to Update on Save instead.

We are currently running on a Digital Ocean Premium Droplet on Cloudways with 16 GB RAM and 8 Core processor with 300 Users visiting us each day and 12 orders per day at this stage. We look forward to ramping it up with ads in the next year.

Comment: Are you on enterprise or community edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update on Save** :The index is set to update whenever a change is saved.

**Update on Schedule** :The index is set to update on schedule according to a cron job.

- On a small store,**Update on Save**  is fine and will add very little
  load.
- If you have a larger store with  multiple admins, working in the
  backend then your indexes could be getting triggered constantly.
  **Update on Save** ties up MySQL and for large stores can take hours to complete. To avoid this, it is recommended setting your
  indexers to **Update on Schedule**.  Then only run the indexers as
  needed (via command)  or via a scheduled cron task.